# Haskell all valuations for variables given domain of values

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For an assignment we have to create a Haskell function which, given a list of (String, [Integer]) (where the Integer list represents the domain of values for the String) tuples gives all possible combinations of Strings and Integers.

So for example, the input valuations [ ("FirstVar", [1..3]), ("SecondVar", [1,2]) ] should yield:

```
[ [("FirstVar", 1), ("SecondVar", 1)], [("FirstVar", 1), ("SecondVar", 2)], [("FirstVar", 2), ("SecondVar", 1)], [("FirstVar", 2), ("SecondVar", 2)], [("FirstVar", 3), ("SecondVar", 1)], [("FirstVar", 3), ("SecondVar", 2)] ]
```

And this should work for n lists. So far, I've only made it work for two lists, but I'm still having trouble with higher-order functions, hence I am confused how I should make this work for n lists.

How I did it for two lists was through a function Valuations:

```
valuations :: (String, [Integer]) -> (String, [Integer]) -> [[(String, Integer)]]
valuations (a, bs) (c, ds) = pairValuations (makeLists(a, bs)) (makeLists(c, ds))

pairValuations :: a -> a -> [a]
pairValuations xs ys = [ [x, y] | x <- xs, y <- ys]

makeLists :: (String, [Integer]) -> [(String, Integer)]
makeLists (a, bs) = [(a, b) | b <- bs]
```

Then valuations ("FirstVar", [1..3]) ("SecondVar", [1,2]) does indeed give the desired result. But I'm having troubles to expand this functionality for multiple lists. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

My solution would be to use `sequence`:

```
valuations = sequence . map makeLists
```

Including @Ørjan Johansen's solutions you could also do:

```
valuations = mapM makeLists
```

or, with `Data.Traversable`:

```
valuations = traverse sequenceA
```

Comment: `sequence . map f` = `mapM f`. Also I cannot resist an attempt at mind-blowing: `import Data.Traversable; valuations = traverse sequenceA`.